# Como ocultar input que está contenido en un datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy realizando un filtrado con inputs en un datatable, también realizo en el datatable un ocultamiento de columnas, pero no esconde los inputs dentro del datatable, espero haya sido claro y me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Aqui el código de lo thead de mi tabla:

```
<div class=row>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Documento</th>
   <th>Fecha creacion</th>
   <th>Descargar</th>
   <th>Visualizar</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <thead class="filters">
  <tr>
   <td>Documento</td>
   <td>Fecha creacion</td>
   <td>Descargar</td>
   <td>Visualizar</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</div>
```

Aqui los jquery:

```
 $('#tabla_bajas .filters td').each( function () {
    var title = $('#tabla_bajas thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );


var table = $('#tabla_bajas').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
    $( 'input', $('.filters td')[colIdx] ).on( 'keyup change', function                () {
        table
            .column( colIdx )
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );
} );


 $('#myCheck1').change(function() {
  table.columns(0).visible(!$(this).is(':checked'))
  console.log(table.columns(0));
   });

  $('#myCheck2').change(function() {
   table.columns([1, 2]).visible(!$(this).is(':checked'))
      })
```

En las funciones de los 2 checkbox quiero ocultar totalmente la columna junto con los inputs pero no lo hace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso considero que cuando utilizas *!$(this).is(':checked')* no estas haciendo referencia al valor del input. Intenta utilizando **!$(this).is(':checked').val()** ya que así obtienes el valor de los input de tipo checkbox que estas utilizando.

La referencia a la anterior respuesta: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()

En caso de no funcionar, recomiendo cambiar tu sintaxis a la siguiente:

```
$('#myCheck1').change(function() {
var inpunt_checkbox = $(this).val();//obtengo el valor que tiene el input
if(input_checkbox == true) {//verificacion del estado del input para ocultar o no la columna
table.columns(0).visible(false);
$('#myCheck1').attr("hidden","true");
//console.log(table.columns(0));
} else {
table.columns(0).visible(true);
$('#myCheck1').attr("hidden","false");
}
});
```

Lo que realizo busco es que al dar click en el checkbox se compruebe en que estado se encuentra y si esta seleccionado entonces oculte la columna y el checkbox, si no, entonces ambos quedan visibles.